# Git merges all the time

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, rebase

A programmer in my team has a very strange issue with a particular Git repository.

He is the only user making changes to the repo, yet, everytime he pushes, Git will make a merge commit message rather than the actual commit message!

It's hard to explain so a picture is better suited:
[image]

At some point it started doing the 'playMakerTest' thing and it never recovered from doing that. Every single commit he now makes and pushes ends up being a merge. Even after cleanly checking out, rebasing the latest commit, moving everything back to master and getting rid of all other branches.

Anyone got an idea why this is happening? I'm really on the brink of just creating a new repo...

Comment: And what happens if other programmers commits anything? (Is the problem related to the "programmer" or the "repository"?)

Comment: Sorry, for forgot to add - when I add a commit it goes just fine. It's only this user on this particular repository - I don't want him to work on other just yet because it might be related to his configuration and it could seriously mess up the history integrity.

Comment: So why are you "*on the brink of just creating a new repo*"? Simply reconfigure/reinstall that programmer's environment

Comment: Because I'm keeping all things open just in case ;) The reason I ask is because I have absolutely no idea which thing in his environment is causing this config-wise.

Comment: From what I gather, he attempted to merge a branch with master and used the command-line for that, then switched back to using TortoiseGit and it has been happening ever since.

Comment: I know nothing about tortoisegit, but if that's a suspect, first confirm it (do a command line commit), then either add it as a tag and correct your question, or at least you know it's irrelevant

Comment: TortoiseGit uses the git command-line under the hood he manually used (msysgit to be exact), its just a fancy UI. Again, it probably triggered some configuration-change but I simply cannot find it when comparing to my configuration. We also tried re-installing git already and wiping all configs (but apparently I'm missing something).

Comment: What does `git config --list | grep branch` say for their machine? Or, better yet, do they have any specific `branch.<branchname>.mergeOptions`?

Comment: @Makoto Nope, nothing of the sort - also compared his output to mine, pretty much equal.

Comment: Something smells fishy here, then.  Are you *certain* their repository is clean?  That includes commits with whitespace changes.

Comment: I checked out cleanly on a different place in the filesystem, went through all config files again and while there is absolutely zero different between both the new and old repro, it now suddenly works. While I've done the exact same procedure time and time again before... what the flying...

Comment: Now there's the little bugger - he now confessed he kept click "Amend Last Commit" when committing stuff when he saw me not clicking it. That doesn't work when stuff is already pushed, right?

Comment: Please delete this question. Glad you found your answer, but its useless for SO.

Comment: Well, the question now is if "Amend Last Commit" causes this behavior. And if so, it's a perfectly valid FAQ entry on "what to check if...".

Comment: Great! delete this question, start a fresh one with the correct details (Without all these irrelevant comments..) and that would be a great question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I have confirmed that "Amend Last Commit" was indeed the issue.

After a commit has already been pushed, amend will still try to correct the latest commit. Upon committing it will notice that the commit it just modified had already been pushed and will throw a merge conflict.

The programmer in question missed all the red flags and just "fixed" the merge conflicts and pushed the changes, as a starting Git user, he just figured it was "supposed to be that way". Until others and I started complaining all his commits are merges and mess up the history integrity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're going to delete this question (as suggested in comments above), but for now I will note one thing:

**`git push` cannot create a merge**.<sup>1</sup>

When you use `git push`, you have your git call up some other git (e.g., via ssh), after which the two git repositories have a little conversation to discuss which objects yours has that theirs doesn't, and what objects you'd like them to set some of their references to point-to.

For instance, in your case you (or more precisely your programmer in your team) might call up the server git instance and say "please change branch `branch` to point to commit `1234567...`".  In order for the server to do that, the server has to *have* commit  `1234567...` so your git may package up that object with any other needed objects, and ship those over, first.

The server-side git *does not* do any merging during this process, it simply accepts whatever objects are needed first, then takes requests like "set `refs/heads/branch` to `1234567...`".  Those requests are run through permission-checking (`pre-receive` and `update` hooks), which typically do things like refuse non-fast-forward updates, or when using fancier systems like gitolite, check whether the remote user has permission to create, delete, or update a particular branch.<sup>2</sup>  If the permissions checks allow it, the server-side git process simply sets the requested references (usually branch-names, sometimes tags; there are also note references and such).

Each of these merges, then, are coming from the user (not server) side, before the `git push` step.  As noted in the comments above **this was due to the user repeatedly amending an existing-but-pushed commit**, which copies the commit to a new ID.  Pushing that new ID will not be a fast-forward operation and will by default be refused; to get it to happen, the user is presumably doing additional merges.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, not by itself, anyway.  Using the hooks mentioned above, it's possible to set up a server such that when it receives a push, it saves any new commit(s), rejects the push itself, and then runs additional separate git commands to create merges using the saved-but-rejected commit(s).  That's quite a twisted mode of operation, and not something people would or should generally do.  (Also, it's not precisely the push creating the merge here, it's the push triggering some other script, and the other script creating the merge.)